# geom_text & geom_jitter are removing all the rows of my df, even when limits are modified

Tags: r, ggplot2

doing simple word-analysis from this df

```
    # A tibble: 22,959 x 4
   word           n    proportion.A proportion.B
   <chr>      <int>        <dbl>        <dbl>
 1 globe        1100     0.00792           NA
 2 people       954      0.00687           NA
 3 world        900      0.00648           NA
 4 flag         719      0.00518           NA
 5 american     646      0.00465           NA
 6 program      634      0.00456           NA
 7 travel       609      0.00438           NA
 8 time         561      0.00404           NA
 9 economic     556      0.00400           NA
10 sociology    529      0.00381           NA
# ... with 22,949 more rows
```

I'm trying to create a plot with geom_abline, & jitter to show a similar frequency in both text A & B through this code

```
ggplot(frequency, aes(x = proportion.A, y = proportion.B, color = abs(proportion.B - proportion.A))) +
  geom_abline(color = "yellow", lty = 2) +
  geom_jitter(alpha = 0.1, size = 2.5, width = 0.3, height = 0.3) +
  xlim(0,0.1) +
  ylim(0,0.1) +
  geom_text(aes(label = word), check_overlap = TRUE, vjust = 1.5) +
  scale_color_gradient(limits = c(0, 0.01), low = "blue", high = "red")
```

When I plot this I only get the plot with the abline and this warning message

```
 Warning messages:
1: Removed 22959 rows containing missing values (geom_point). 
2: Removed 22959 rows containing missing values (geom_text).
```

I know that this warning can occur when there's a limit issue, I've tried using scale_""_continuous & scale_log10 but to no avail. Any idea where I need to look? 
Thank you

Comment: How many NA values do you have in each column ? Are you sure you have some rows with both values for A and B ?

Comment: All rows have at least one value for a or b

Comment: but do you have rows with values for both ?

Comment: Yes there are rows that have value for both

Comment: The fact that you're getting warning of removal of all points for BOTH geoms is indicating to me that the issue is within the `aes(...)` call on the main `ggplot` item.  Could be your `color=` term, which may be having some issues due to NA.  My suggestion is to try to plot without the `color` term (ex. even a simple `geom_point()` call after the `ggplot` call.  Then I suggest to do the calculation you're doing in color assigned to a new column in your df: `frequency$color.abs <- your calculation here`.  You may have to add a `rm.na = TRUE` here.  Hard to see without the dataset..